# Overleaf places Table at the end of the document

Tags: tables, positioning

I have several tables in my document which are all placed at the right place. However,  two tables are now suddenly displayed at the end of my document, behind the references. I did not change anything in the code of the table. I now tried to

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

alter from htbp to h!, H and so forth. However, nothing changes. Two tables are always displayed at the end of the document. I work with overleaf and have no clue why the tables suddenly changed their position.
I would be super grateful for any help.

Comment: the point of the `table` environment is to allow tables to move, so you presumably have one table that can not be placed for some reason eg too big for a text page, too small for a float page.  If one table can not be placed then all following tables will go to the end as they are kept in order.

Comment: This is not related to overleaf, it is standard latex behaviour. Note that your statement that using `[H]` does not change this can not be right, if you use float package and `H` the table will not move, if you use `H` without the `float` package you should get an error about unknown float option.

Comment: Great, thanks! There was indeed one table which I could now move using [H] and place above the references again. The next table also followed suit as you said. Thanks!